# How is the "1:1 meetings" question unclear?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[My manager wants regular one-on-one meetings: is this bad?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/71687/my-manager-wants-regular-one-on-one-meetings-is-this-bad) was asked by somebody new to the workplace who was surprised by a notice for regular 1:1 meetings with his manager.  The question identifies the type of work and asks if this is a common practice.

The question was put on hold as "unclear what you're asking".  I see no comments explaining what is unclear, and several answers that understood it well enough (and do not appear to have conflicting understandings).

What is unclear about this question?

---

**Question has been reopened** as of 2016-07-21 14:26:28Z.

Comment: Just added final vote to reopen,  looks straight forward as a question to me.

Comment: There's nothing unclear about this question.

Comment: Yes, but should still be closed with the actual reason since this is nearly the definition of Company specific.

Comment: I always interpret "unclear what you're asking" to mean "unclear *why* you're asking (us)". This is not without precedent: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215705/202356. When viewed this way, the question is closeable for exactly the same reason. By the way, "what is the purpose of 1:1 meetings?" is not the same question as "why did my manager call me for a 1:1 meeting?"

Answer (score 2):

I don't feel that "as unclear what you're asking" is the issue.

I feel like this question can be best answered by the Manager.
We don't know why his Manager wants the meeting. Only his Manager can answer this.

My answer to this question would have been basicly:
We can only gossip, go ask your Manager.

To give it more "context" I would add 100 reasons why he mightve and answer if this is a common question or not. But I don't feel that helps anyone. So I didnt answer, comment or vtc.

Also I don't like the answer of justin cave and highly doubt it is the case.
If it was a montly maybe, but weekly man I wouldnt get work done here.

Comment: By that reasoning, questions about how to present things on resumes or in cover letters are company-specific (each hiring manager is different), as are questions about negotiating salary (some companies are more flexible than others), as are questions about socializing with coworkers (every place is different)... what do you think is *not* company-specific?

Comment: "How to present things on resumes" is not Company-Specific´.
"Negotiating Salary" Many of These questions are People who accepted a Job and dislike their "benefits" and complain, but still not Company specific.

Comment: "socializing with coworkers" IDK, it might be? Honestly I see/seen alot of answers which basicly say that every place is different bla bla bla, do a judgement roll and hope for the best. Now this is kinda narrow minded as I don't really read the answers to the qeustions. :D

Comment: Isn't "how to X on resumes" just code for "how do I get my target company to hire me"?  Which would be company-specific, by your reasoning.  "What's the purpose of 1:1 meetings" is no more company-specific than that.  Similarly, what tactics for negotiating salary can be company-specific; some companies have rigid job-grade systems.  There are plenty of questions here that *are* company-specific (or employee-specific) and they rightly get closed; I just don't think this current question is one of them.

Comment: can we agree to disagree? :X

Answer (score 0):

It's not unclear, it's company-specific.

Please review the reasons which the five close voters chose for closing this question. Five people certainly did not vote to close this question because it's unclear.

Comment: 1:1 meetings with your manager are a *common* practice in my experience.  That's hardly company-specific, meaning a question that can only be answered by one's company.  But thanks for pointing out that not all the close voters agreed on the reason.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: And every manager's motivation for holding frequent one-on-one meetings is... Company-specific.